# How to ignore match case for serializable id on the session.get() method in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ignore-case

Please help on how to ignore match case for serializable id on the `session.get()` method in hibernate. I don't want to handle at the criteria, I need it at the `session.get()` method.

```
User user = (User ) session.get(User.class, id);
```

**Eg**: `US123` and `us123` as id should give me a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get it out of the box, because those are two different ids (you could have two distinct users with ids `US123` and `us123`).

You can however make sure that you always store uppercase (or lowercase, whatever you prefer) ids when you create users; then you could fetch users by id like this:

```
User user = (User ) session.get(User.class, id.toUpperCase());
```